# Memory exceptions when scraping Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to scrape all the groups a user is a member of in Active Directory (including groups that they are indirect members of), but I am running into memory exception errors.

Latest error message passed was:

> Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

The code I run is started in a backgroundworker on a schedule.

I have looked through ALL the SO active directory group scraping posts, and tried as many of the iterations of this process as I could get to work. This one will (usually) work if i don't run it on a schedule. Sometimes it will crash the program though.

Our Active Directory database is quite considerably large.

Any help you could offer with this would be great. I don't mind it taking a bit longer, speed is not an overly great concern, as long as I can get it to perform well, and correctly.

Here's what I have:

```
        DataTable resultsTable = new DataTable();
        resultsTable.Columns.Add("EmailID");
        resultsTable.Columns.Add("UserID");
        resultsTable.Columns.Add("memberOf");
        resultsTable.Columns.Add("groupType");
        resultsTable.Columns.Add("record_date");

        try
        {
            string RecordDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(format: "dd/MM/yyyy", provider: CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));

            string ou = "OU=Groups,OU=nonya,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=net";

            using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "my.domain.net", ou))
            {
                using (GroupPrincipal GroupPrin = new GroupPrincipal(context))
                {
                    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(GroupPrin))
                    {
                        using (var results = searcher.FindAll())
                        {
                            foreach (var result in results)
                            {
                                DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                                string GUID = de.Guid.ToString();
                                string testname1 = de.Name;
                                string testParentName1 = de.Parent.Name;
                                string MasterGroupname = testname1.Substring(3, (testname1.Length - 3));
                                string type = testParentName1.Substring(3, (testParentName1.Length - 3));

                                using (var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Guid, GUID))
                                {
                                    using (var users = group.GetMembers(true))
                                    {
                                        foreach (Principal user in users)
                                        {
                                            DataRow dr1 = resultsTable.NewRow();

                                            dr1["EmailID"] = user.UserPrincipalName;
                                            dr1["UserID"] = user.SamAccountName;
                                            dr1["memberOf"] = MasterGroupname;
                                            dr1["groupType"] = type;
                                            dr1["record_date"] = RecordDate;

                                            resultsTable.Rows.Add(dr1);
                                            user.Dispose();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        //Table is uploaded to SQL database here, unless it crashes before reaching this point
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            logger.Error($"ADGroupScrape error. System says: {E.Message}");
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            resultsTable.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: You do not need following line :  resultsTable.Rows.Add(dr1);.   This line already added the new line so you are adding it twice : DataRow dr1 = resultsTable.NewRow();

Comment: I was under the impression that the newrow line simply declared/assigned a new row, but did not add it to the datatable. Then once the columns and contents had been declared/manipulted they needed to be added/committed to the table in memory?

Comment: This is about the third time I've seen this problem in the last week.  The NewRow method adds a new row to the table and returns a variable with the row.

Comment: This could play a large part in reducing the amount of memory used by the datatable then. I'll give this a shot. Thanks @jdweng

Comment: I set a rowcount to increment on every row that should be added to the datatable, and removed the ...rows.add(dr1); line. when i break the program, my rowcount says the datatable should contain 135 rows, but the datatable contains 0.

Comment: found a link to microsoft doc that states you need the rows.add to add the data to the data row collection. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-data-to-a-datatable)

Comment: DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
            }
            int rows = dt.Rows.Count;

Comment: you've set up a datatable and added 100 rows to it...
the only difference (apart from the data) is that declaring newrow first gives the ability to add or manipulate the data using column names rather than as an array.
Either way you still need the rows.add().

Comment: Sorry, I do not use the NewRow.  I use DataRow = dt.Rows.Add() instead.  My way saves a line of code.  You do not need the dispose since the using statement will automatically dispose user.

Comment: no worries, im always open to suggestions on improvements/enhancements. so all input is always appreciated. I was unsure about the dispose, as user is not part of the using statement it is in the foreach within the using. figured i'd leave it in there just in case.

Comment: You can't dispose an object that is already disposed.  I've gotten exceptions and your exception may be due to the extra dispose.

Comment: cool, i'll give it a shot. Thanks @jdweng

Comment: still getting the error.

Comment: Does it work if you use a smaller folder.  Try changing "my.domain.net" to only one folder.

Comment: Tried changing the 'Platform' in Configuration Manager to x64 (was set to "Any CPU") and it seems to have run without error. Not sure if this is just a fluke or not, but will see tomorrow morning when it is set to run again.

Comment: I had similar issue last year with memory exception and going to x64 solved the issue.

Comment: @jdweng All that does is let your application use more memory. It doesn't solve the problem of your application using more memory than it needs to.

Comment: @Gabriel Luci : If the application needs the memory, than it is correct.  My application needed the memory.  I had a machine with 8GB memory.  Application ran find on 32GB machine.  To get code to run on 8GB I had to use x64.  I looked for memory leaks and there were none.The machine used 4GB before application ran.

Comment: @jdweng Fair enough. But in this case, there is no need for the app to use 4GB of memory.

Comment: The 32GB machine was also crashing and had a lot of memory still available.  It appeared that the Net Library had different limits in normal mode and x64 mode.  Going to x64 got both the 8GB and 32GB to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue didn't appear to be with my code, but thank you all for the suggestions in cleaning it up.
I changed the Target Platform in Configuration Manager (Visual Studio) to **X64**, as it was originally set to "**Any CPU**", and my code now runs successfully every time.

Comment: Following up, that has been a week now with no errors.

Comment: This might avoid the out of memory exception, but it would not solve the cause of the problem: the overuse of memory. Changing it to a 64-bit application will just let it use more memory, thus not maxing out so early. If you check the memory consumption, it's probably still eating a ton of memory while it's running, and likely running a whole lot slower than it could be because of that.

Comment: I was trying to find good documentation on how much memory a 32-bit application can use. It's either 2GB or 4GB, but either way, it's *way* more than your application should be using.

Answer (score 1):

Disposing each object at the end of the loop will probably solve your problem (`result.Dispose()`). I've had memory problems with long loops when working with AD. Assuming you're working with thousands of results, and you're allocating memory for each, and there's no break between processing each result, the garbage collector doesn't have an opportunity to clean up for you.

But you're also unnecessarily going back out to AD to search for the group you already found (`GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity`). That would also increase memory consumption, but also slow down the whole operation. Instead, just cast `result` to a `GroupPrincipal` so you can call `.GetMembers()` on it.

Unrelated, but helpful: When you have multiple `using` blocks nested like that, you can combine them all into one block. It saves you indenting so much.

This is what your code would look like with all those suggestions:

```cs
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "my.domain.net", ou))
using (GroupPrincipal GroupPrin = new GroupPrincipal(context))
using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(GroupPrin))
using (var results = searcher.FindAll())
{
    foreach (GroupPrincipal result in results)
    {
        DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
        string GUID = de.Guid.ToString();
        string testname1 = de.Name;
        string testParentName1 = de.Parent.Name;
        string MasterGroupname = testname1.Substring(3, (testname1.Length - 3));
        string type = testParentName1.Substring(3, (testParentName1.Length - 3));

        using (var users = result.GetMembers(true))
        {
            foreach (Principal user in users)
            {
                DataRow dr1 = resultsTable.NewRow();

                dr1["EmailID"] = user.UserPrincipalName;
                dr1["UserID"] = user.SamAccountName;
                dr1["memberOf"] = MasterGroupname;
                dr1["groupType"] = type;
                dr1["record_date"] = RecordDate;

                user.Dispose();
            }
        }
        result.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This will probably work, but could probably still be much faster. Using `Principal` objects (and the whole `AccountManagement` namespace) is a wrapper around `DirectoryEntry`/`DirectorySearcher` which makes things somewhat easier for you, but at the cost of performance. Using `DirectoryEntry`/`DirectorySearcher` directly is *always* faster.

If you want to experiment with that, I wrote a couple articles that will help:

- [Active Directory: Better performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)
- [Active Directory: Find all the members of a group](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/11/30/find-all-members-of-group.html)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of months down the line and i started getting out of memory exceptions again.
added pagination (which i didnt actually know you could do) and it seems to have resolved the issue. The line i added was `((DirectorySearcher)searcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher()).PageSize = 500;` in between the searcher declaration and the `searcher.FindAll()`.

```
                    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(GroupPrin))
                    {
                        ((DirectorySearcher)searcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher()).PageSize = 500;
                        using (var results = searcher.FindAll())
                        {
```